# Connecting Swift2 iOs app to Java web application

Tags: java, php, mysql, servlets, swift2

I have created a web app using java servlets and was wondering if there was a possibility of connection ios apps written in swift2 to the MySQL database in the web application. I have found information on how to connect android applications to the java servlet on my web app to be able to make queries to the database but the only information I can get about connecting the swift2 app to the database is through php and from what I have read, Java Servlets and php cannot be used together. Has anyone a solution to this problem?